# Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have ruby 2.0 that is what comes up with `ruby -v` command

but I want to use ruby 1.9.3 because a gem I want to use for a project only suppoerts up to that version.

I have included:

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

in my gemfile and get the following error when running bundle install:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
```

how can I use ruby 1.9.3? Where can I download it from I cannot find it? I still want to keep ruby 2.0 since I use it for a bunch of other projects how can I use both for different projects?

I am on a windows.

Comment: Have you tried googling "download ruby 1.9.3"?

Comment: yes downloaded it, just need to figure out how to use it now

Answer (score 0):

First of all the download: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives

If you run it from cmd, you have to change the PATH variable to your target ruby version.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by change the PATH variable to target by version? If you could show example code that would be great. On the command line typing: "PATH=ruby 1.9.3" would do the trick or what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe you hit google for some questions. -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29      You must point it to the the folder where the binarys are located. For ex: SET PATH=C:\ruby123\bin\